# Mandar a llamar a un archivo php en JavaScript con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

Hola lo que pasa es que quiero que aparesca una tabla al presionar un boton,
el id del boton lo llamo al JavaScript y de hay genero la funcion para que lo mande a otro archivo php con ajax y hay crear mi tabla, lo que pasa es que no se como hacerlo necesito ayuda

**Este es el JavaScript**

```
function btnMinformacion(){  

    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/TablaMinformacion.php'

    })
}
```

Como ven tengo otro archivo llamado TablaMinformacion y quiero crear una tabla con php dentro de ese archivo y que se abra cuando yo doy click en el boton.

El boton si funciona ya que si yo pongo esto: aparece el mensaje.

```
function btnMinformacion(){  
    alert("hola");
}
```

Ahora yo quiero hacer la tabla esto es lo que tengo en el php:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$conexion = conexion();
'<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
  </tr>
</table>'
 $conexion=null;
?>
```

Segun yo esto esta bien el unico problema es en JavaScript no se como mandar al php para que abra la tabla ahora.

Comment: Hola cual es la función exactamente de llamar aun archivo php para que se muestre la tabla, por que simplemente no pintas tu tabla en el mismo archivo pero con el atributo display:none; y con javascript enlazas un evento Onclick que cambie el atributo de la tabla por display:inline; o lo que requieras. espero haberme dado a entender

Comment: Como quieres mostrar la tabla? dentro de la misma página o quieres que te lleve a otra pagina? si usas ajax, entiendo que necesitar la tabla en la misma página cierto?

Answer (score 0):

Si usas AJAX entiendo que necesitas mostrar esa tabla en la misma página donde está el botón.

Como en php ya tienes la creación de la tabla puedes hacer que tu php le regrese en string la tabla y desde js poner ese string como html en la página.

Javascript (usando ECMAScript 2015)

```
var btnMinformacion = () => {  

    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/TablaMinformacion.php'

    }).done( tuTabla =>{

       var elElementoDondePonerLaTabla = document.querySelector("#elIdDelElemento");

       elElementoDondePonerLaTabla.innerHTML = tuTabla;

    })
}
```

En el código anterior obtienes la respuesta que te enviaría un php cómo este:

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
$conexion = conexion();

$tabla = '<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
  </tr>
</table>';

 $conexion=null;
 echo $tabla;

?>
```

Al final necesitarías un HTML así:

```
<button onclick="btnMinformacion">Mostrar tabla</button>
<div id="elIdDelElemento"></div>
```

Comment: Me fue muy util al aplicarlo con una consulta Mysqli. gracias